# Multiple ORDER BY DESC will not use index in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, indexing, pagination

I'm trying to create some queries in order to implement a cursor pagination (something like this: https://shopify.engineering/pagination-relative-cursors) on Postgres. In my implementation I'm trying to reach an efficient pagination even with *ordering NON-unique columns*.

I'm struggling to do that efficiently, in particular on the query that retrieves the previous page given a specific cursor.

The table that I'm using (>3M records) to test these query is very simple, and it has this structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "placemarks" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL DEFAULT,
    "assetId" text,
    "createdAt" timestamptz,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

I have an index on the `id` field clearly and also an index on the `assetId` column.

This is the query I'm using for retrieving the next page given a cursor composed by the latest ID and the latest assetId:

```sql
 SELECT
    *
FROM
    "placemarks"
WHERE
    "assetId" > 'CURSOR_ASSETID'
    or("assetId" = 'CURSOR_ASSETID'
        AND id > CURSOR_INT_ID)
ORDER BY
    "assetId",
    id
LIMIT 5;
```

This query is actually pretty fast, it uses the indexes and it allows to handle also duplicated values on `assetId` by using the unique ID field in order to avoid skipping duplicated rows with same `CURSOR_ASSETID` values.

```
  ->  Sort  (cost=25709.62..25726.63 rows=6803 width=2324) (actual time=0.128..0.138 rows=5 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: ""assetId"", id"
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 45kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on placemarks  (cost=271.29..25596.63 rows=6803 width=2324) (actual time=0.039..0.088 rows=11 loops=1)
"              Recheck Cond: (((""assetId"")::text > 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text) OR ((""assetId"")::text = 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text))"
"              Filter: (((""assetId"")::text > 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text) OR (((""assetId"")::text = 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text) AND (id > CURSOR_INT_ID)))"
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
              Heap Blocks: exact=10
              ->  BitmapOr  (cost=271.29..271.29 rows=6803 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.034 rows=0 loops=1)
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""placemarks_assetId_key""  (cost=0.00..263.45 rows=6802 width=0) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=11 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: ((""assetId"")::text > 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""placemarks_assetId_key""  (cost=0.00..4.44 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: ((""assetId"")::text = 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text)"
Planning time: 0.201 ms
Execution time: 0.194 ms
```

The issue is when I try to get the same page but with the query that should return me the previous page:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    placemarks
WHERE
    "assetId" < 'CURSOR_ASSETID'
    or("assetId" = 'CURSOR_ASSETID'
        AND id < CURSOR_INT_ID)
ORDER BY
    "assetId" desc,
    id desc
LIMIT 5;
```

With this query no indexes are used, even if it would be much faster:

```
Limit  (cost=933644.62..933644.63 rows=5 width=2324)
  ->  Sort  (cost=933644.62..944647.42 rows=4401120 width=2324)
"        Sort Key: ""assetId"" DESC, id DESC"
        ->  Seq Scan on placemarks  (cost=0.00..860543.60 rows=4401120 width=2324)
"              Filter: (((""assetId"")::text < 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text) OR (((""assetId"")::text = 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text) AND (id < CURSOR_INT_ID)))"
```

I've noticied that by forcing the usage of indexes with `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;` the query appears to be using the indexes and it performs better and faster. The query plan resulting:

```
Limit  (cost=12.53..12.54 rows=5 width=108) (actual time=0.532..0.555 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=12.53..12.55 rows=6 width=108) (actual time=0.524..0.537 rows=5 loops=1)
        Sort Key: assetid DESC, id DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ""placemarks""  (cost=8.33..12.45 rows=6 width=108) (actual time=0.274..0.340 rows=14 loops=1)"
"              Recheck Cond: ((assetid < 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text) OR (assetid = 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text))"
"              Filter: ((assetid < 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text) OR ((assetid = 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text) AND (id < 14)))"
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
              Heap Blocks: exact=1
              ->  BitmapOr  (cost=8.33..8.33 rows=7 width=0) (actual time=0.152..0.159 rows=0 loops=1)
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""placemarks_assetid_idx""  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=6 width=0) (actual time=0.108..0.110 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (assetid < 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""placemarks_assetid_idx""  (cost=0.00..4.15 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (assetid = 'CURSOR_ASSETID'::text)"
Planning time: 1.319 ms
Execution time: 0.918 ms
```

Any clue to optimize the second query in order to use always the indexes?

Postgres DB version: 10.20

Comment: You need an index on `(assetid desc, id desc)` if the second query should use an index instead

Comment: Does it not work with a reverse scanning of the indexes?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But wouldn't you expect the `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause to make an index less useful or non usable?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: true, I was more focused on the `order by` part.

Comment: So the main problem is with the WHERE conditions?

Comment: Your last plan doesn't make any sense.  How could it show `assetId > 'CURSOR_ASSETID'` in the plan when the query clearly has that comparison reversed?

Comment: @jjanes I've corrected the post

Answer (score 0):

The fast performance of your first query seems to be down to luck of where your constant 'CURSOR_ASSETID' falls in the distribution of that column.  Or maybe this luck is not luck but is how it will always be?

For good performance more generally, including for reverse sorting, you need to write your query with a tuple comparator, not an OR comparator.

```
WHERE
    ("assetId",id) < ('something',500000)
```

If you are using a version before incremental sorting was introduced in v13, or if "assetId" can have a large number of ties, then you will need a multicolumn index on `("assetId",id)` to get optimal performance.

And there is no reason to decorate the index with DESC, as PostgreSQL knows how to read the index backwards.  Decorating the index is needed when the two columns have different ordering than each other, as then you would need to read the undecorated index "spirally" rather than either completely forward or completely backwards.  (But that wouldn't work well here anyway, as tuple comparators can't have different orderings between the columns.)

Comment: Thank you! I've already tried with the tuple comparator with no luck.. I'm using Postgres 10.20. Even with a multicolumn index the DESC sorting has the same behaviour, while in the ASC sorting no problem

Comment: I get robustly good behavior on v10 provided I both use the tuple comparator and have the multicolumn index.  So I can't reproduce the problem.  Could you give the EXPLAIN plan for the case where you write it with the tuple comparator and have the multicolumn index, as well as showing the query itself and the CREATE for the index.

Comment: Index: `create index on "placemarks" ("assetId", id);`

Comment: Query: `
select * from "placemarks"
 where ("assetId", id) < ('assetID', 14)
 order by "assetId" desc, id desc
 limit 5
;`

Comment: I'm sorry, probably something is wrong with my database.. I've seen that with some tables it uses the index, in others it prefers sequential scans... But the query, the type of the columns are the same, and the table size roughly the same

Comment: @bertonc96 You should add things by editing your question, the unformatted text in comments is almost unreadable.  But the seq scan you posted appears to have been on an almost empty table.